# What would be the long form of the following statment?

Tags: c++, shorthand

I was looking at some code which came with the following short-hand statement

```
score = ((initialPlayer == player) ? CAPTURE_SCORE : -CAPTURE_SCORE) + recursive_solver(lastMap, initialPlayer, findOpponent(player), 1 + rounds);
```

I think that I understand the first portion of the code,

```
if(initialPlayer == player){
   score = CAPTURE_SCORE;
}
else
   score = -CAPTURE_SCORE;
```

but im confused to how the +recursive_solver function is added to this, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

As stated above I tried to write out the statement in a longer from thats easier for me to read. My best guess is that the recursive solver function is then added to the score of the if-else statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(initialPlayer == player)
   score = CAPTURE_SCORE + recursive_solver(lastMap, initialPlayer, findOpponent(player), 1 + rounds);
else
   score = -CAPTURE_SCORE + recursive_solver(lastMap, initialPlayer, findOpponent(player), 1 + rounds);
```

Explanation:

```
A = (C ? B : D) + E;
```

If `C` is `true`: `A = (B) + E;`
If `C` is `false`: `A = (D) + E;`
In sum

```
if (C)
  A = B + E;
else // if (!C)
  A = D + E;
```

Comment: The `+ E` is redundant in both `if..else` branches and should be refactored out after the `if..else`. After all, that is how the compiler is going to evaluate the original code anyway

Comment: @RemyLebeau The compiler does not evaluate like you show it. Removing the redundant `+ E` will require storing the intermediate result in a temporary variable or in A, it's not an equivalent code.

Comment: @273K The compiler will evaluate `(C ? B : D)` and store its result in a temp variable/register, and then add the result of `E` to that, finally assigning the result of that to `A`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is under the hood. You can't access intermediate evaluations from the code. With an explicit temporary variable or with `A`, you can access the intermediate values, it's a bit other logic.

Comment: @RemyLebeau With some classes for `score` it could make a difference in behaviour to store a temporary value of `CAPTURE_SCORE` or `-CAPTURE_SCORE`. It would not even work to store a const reference to CAPTURE_SCORE (whether it is a literal or an accessible variable), as `CAPTURE_SCORE` can be used directly and `-CAPTURE_SCORE` is calculated first with the unary operator. However, one could put the result of `recursive_solver` into a temporary variable before the `if` and add it respectively, as the operation order is not defined anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
score = ((initialPlayer == player) ? CAPTURE_SCORE : -CAPTURE_SCORE) + recursive_solver(lastMap, initialPlayer, findOpponent(player), 1 + rounds);
```

Equals to

```
if(initialPlayer == player) {
    score = CAPTURE_SCORE;
} else {
    score = -CAPTURE_SCORE;
}
score += recursive_solver(lastMap, initialPlayer, findOpponent(player), 1 + rounds);
```

Comment: One could argue, whether to use another temporary variable for storing the first part of the result than also using `score` for it. If `score` is a custom object type, you would see the difference.